# Current means to extend custom element in Dart Polymer?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am attempting to create some custom elements that all extend a single custom element, using Polymer and Dart.  Following the directions from Seth Ladd's G+ post here (although outdated and unmaintained, still the only reference I could find for extending custom [non-DOM] elements):

https://plus.google.com/+SethLadd/posts/7Ed4GUWZB26

Here is a stripped-down example code of the type of thing I'm attempting to do:

Base element HTML:

```dart
<link rel='import' href='packages/polymer/polymer.html'>
<polymer-element name='base-element'>
<template>
  ... stuff here relating to template ...
</template>
<script type='application/dart' src='base-element.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Base element Dart:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@CustomTag('base-element')
class BaseElement extends PolymerElement {
  BaseElement.created() : super.created();
  ... other base class stuff here ...
}
```

First custom sub-classed element HTML:

```dart
<link rel='import' href='packages/polymer/polymer.html'>
<link rel='import' href='base-element.html'>
<polymer-element name='sub-element-1' extends='base-element'>
<script type='application/dart' src='base-element.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

First custom sub-classed element Dart:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'base-element.dart';
@CustomTag('sub-element-1')
class SubElement1 extends BaseElement {
  SubElement1.created() : super.created();
  ... other subclass stuff here ...
}
```

The main issue I'm having is an error the Dart Editor is giving me (during runtime):

"Breaking on exception: NotSupportedError: Registration failed for type 'sub-element-1'. The tag name specified in 'extends' is a custom element name. Use inheritance instead."

The editor appears to dislike the **extends='base-element'** part in the sub-element's HTML.  But if you take that part out, the base element's templated HTML is ignored, even though the Dart code does use inheritance.  So, ultimately my questions for this post is:

***How do you currently create custom elements that extend other custom elements, so they use the base element's template?***

Any help and/or info would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: The core- and paper-elements make use of extending elements. They are Polymer.js but most things apply to Polymer.dart as well. For example how `<shadow>` is applied for placing the content of the super element.

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo mistake on my part that messed everything up.  I had thought about deleting this question once I found this out, but figured its relevance seemed worth keeping.

Answer (score 1):

I apparently had a typo when importing the base element's Dart file (in my actual code, not the example above), which threw everything else off.  This still is the correct means to extend a custom element, and a sub-element will use the base element's template.  Sometimes the littlest of things can cause the greatest of headaches when programming...

Comment: I am intrigued by the suggestion "use inheritance instead". Are there any examples of using inheritance rather than extension?